# Expected number of throws to get a 6 on a die: why is this argument wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question:** What is the expected number of throws of a fair die to obtain a 6?

**Answer:** 6 throws. This can be computed in many ways. For instance, see solutions of Problem 4 in [this link](https://mbapreponline.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/fifty_challenging_problems_in__2.pdf).

My question is what is wrong with my logic. Suppose I want to know the probability of obtaining a 6 after $k$ throws. The probability of that is

$$P(k) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{6}$$

We also have $$\sum_{k=1}^4P(k) > \frac{1}{2}.$$

Why does this not imply that the expected number of throws is 4 (or slightly less than 4)? I think my misunderstanding is conceptual.

Comment: You are confusing the median with the expected value, so at least we have a *semantic* misunderstanding.

Comment: Well, even though $\sum_{k=1}^4P(k) > \frac{1}{2}$, the remaining $P(k)$ is not bounded until $k \leq 8$. Let say in an extreme case $\sum_{k=1}^4P(k) = 0.999 > \frac{1}{2}$, but if the remaining $0.001$ is at $P(1e7) = 0.001$, then you still have the expectation to be more than $0.001 * 1e7 = 1e4$

Comment: Consider a simple scenario of having three boxes... In one of the boxes there is \$1.  In another box there is \$5.  In the third box there is \$1,000,000.  We can ask "*if we pick a box at random, what is the* **expected value** *of the amount of money found?*"  Your argument here is like saying "*Well, there's over a 50% chance of finding 5 or less dollars, so why isn't the expected value 5 or less?*" while ignoring the influence of the amount of money that can be found in the third box.  Look again at the definition of expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are using an informal/colloquial interpretation of "expected" as "more likely than not" vs the mathematical definition "Average number of throws to get a 6" where the average is taken over an infinite number of experiments where we roll a die until we get a six and record that number.

You compute the expected value of a discrete random variable $X$ with probability distribution  $p(x)$ as

$$E[X] = \sum_{x \in \text{Range}(X)} xp(x)$$

In your case for rolling a fair die till we get a 6, we have:

$$E[X] = \sum_{x =1}^{\infty} x \left[\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-1}\frac{1}{6}\right]$$

The form of the distribution $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-1}\frac{1}{6}$ shows that $X$ has a [Geometric(p) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#) with $p=\frac16$, which has expected value $\frac1p = 6$.

So if you repeated the experiment with rolling the die and kept updating the sample mean of the number of throws needed, it would converge to $6$.

The logic you are using is to say that I expect to roll no more than 4 time, more often than not. You aren't actually getting a number you expect, you're getting an upper bound (and a very loose one at $\approx 50%$).

A more useful approach to this probabilistic way of thinking is to calculate a prediction interval using the distribution. You want to pick two positive integers, $l,u$ such that $P(l\leq X \leq u)$ is high (e.g., 90% or higher). Then you can say you are p% confident that the next time you try the experiment, you will need at least $l$ and at most $u$ rolls to get a 6.